# Android, How to set qualifiers in order to support 4.7" devices?

Tags: android, user-interface, qualifiers

I have designed different UIs based on different qualifiers like drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi. As you can see in following image when I'm testing on 4.3" size mobile sets like SG2, UI is match with screen. However, when I test on 4.7" deices like SG3 and Atrix there are some gaps that it's not nice.

So, I want to redesign screen for these devices based on new dimensions. I read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) However, I didn't find a solution. I tried to add new UI in drawable-xdpi but it affected my current design on 4.3" devices. I tried to use swdp, wdp and hdp however result was not satisfactory.

What is you suggestion? any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, You put those Images into {*}dpi folder .. Right ?
As you might already know, you put your normal-resolution (the resolution which is most suited for your application - device size and resolution) images into "mdpi" folder .. If your application is lunched in extraLarge device with very-high resolution (xdpi) , it would enlarge the images to 2.0 ratio and if the device is large and high resolution (hdpi), it would enlarge the images to 1.5 ratio. And android will squeeze the image size to 0.75 ratio if the device has low dpi & small size . 
But, if it is not enough for you (it wasn't not enough for me), you could simply find out the destination device resolution and resize the images to yourself .. 
All you have to do is find out (have to calculate it for yourself) the **constant** to adjust the resolution of the image. eg; 0.6 (according to the discovered screen resolution, you will multiply the width & height of the image with that **constant**.
Here is my example :

```
Display currentScreen = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point dimension = new Point();
    currentScreen.getSize(dimension);
    //int widthPixel = dimension.x;
    int heightPixel = dimension.y;
    System.out.println("Screen Resolution (Height) : "+heightPixel);

    int imgHeight;
    imgHeight = (int) Math.floor(heightPixel * 0.6);

    int widthSeparator = (int) dimension.y/13;
    System.out.println("Width Separator : "+widthSeparator);

    //imgHeight = 240;

    System.out.println("Image Resolution (Height) : "+imgHeight);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamCR = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParamCR.setMargins(widthSeparator, 0, 0, 0);

    //FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamL = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //layoutParamL.setMargins(-30, 0, 0, 0);

    ImageView leftCover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.magCoverLeft);
    leftCover.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    leftCover.setMaxHeight(imgHeight);
    leftCover.setLayoutParams(layoutParamCR);
    leftCover.setImageBitmap(null);

    ImageView cover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.magCover);
    cover.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    cover.setMaxHeight(imgHeight);
    cover.setLayoutParams(layoutParamCR);
    cover.setImageBitmap(coverImages[0]);

    ImageView rightCover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.magCoverRight);
    rightCover.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    rightCover.setMaxHeight(imgHeight);
    rightCover.setLayoutParams(layoutParamCR);
    rightCover.setImageBitmap(coverImages[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks dear Aung, Images are not stored in device and all of them comes from Internet and Image views dynamically generates based on number of images. However, I got your idea. Thanks. let me test it to see what is the result on different screen sizes...

Comment: You are welcome.. I thought your images is in {*}dpi folder .. 
My example would be more suited for the images which are coming from the Internet as I wrote it that way ..